# Textbox and Button suddenly disappear from webpage after scrollbar added

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Hi I was trying to create a scrollbar for the chat page for the site I'm building, and ever since I added the scrollbar in (overflow), after about 5 seconds (about when the AJAX is triggered), the textbox and button that are right under the field used for displaying messages disappear, namely the MessageTextBox and SendButton.

Here is the code for my html page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well center" style="width:50%">
            <a>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server">
                </asp:Timer>
            </a>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tim" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Timer ID="tim" Interval="5000" Enabled="true" OnTick="UpdateChat" runat="server"></asp:Timer>
                    <div style="overflow: auto; height: 220px; width: 100%;">
                    <center>
                        <asp:Textbox ID="ChatLabel" textmode="MultiLine" style="overflow:auto;width:80%;height:200px" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
                    </center>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:TextBox ID="MessageTextBox" runat="server" Width="438px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="SendButton" runat="server" Text="Send"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Initial notes: You have an un-closed `<div>`, and `<center>` isn't supported HTML5. I'd fix the `<div>` first and make sure that the issue isn't caused by a side-effect of your browser trying to fix it for you.

Comment: @Santi I didn't notice that. The center tag seems to work for me but yes it seems the problem was caused by the missing div tag. Thank you.